# Sending JSON array and UIImageView in the same NSURLRequest

Tags: php, ios, objective-c, json, uiimageview

I'm currently trying to send a JSON array and an UIImageView in the same NSURLRequest in order to avoid multiple network calls to my database. Following the suggests given in the other answers, I've written a function in Objective C which is the following:

```
    NSDictionary *textFields = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:self.reviewTexfField.text, @"review",
self.rateView.rating, @"grade", nil];

    if([NSJSONSerialization isValidJSONObject:textFields]){


            NSError* error;
            NSData *jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:textFields options:0 error:&error];
            NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu", (unsigned long)[jsonData length]];
            NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://domain.something/file.php"];
            NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
            NSString *boundary = @"---------------------------14737809831466499882746641449";
            NSString *contentType = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"multipart/form-data; application/json; boundary=%@", boundary];
            [request addValue:contentType forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
            [request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];
            [request setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];

            [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

            NSMutableData *body = [NSMutableData data];

            // Appending image.
            NSString *imageName = @"A name";
            [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

            [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"photo\"; filename=\"%@.jpg\"\r\n", imageName] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
            [body appendData:[@"Content-Type: application/octet-stream\r\n\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

            [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

            NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(self.immagineRecensione.image, 0.5);
            [body appendData:imageData];


            //Appending JSON request
            [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
            [request setHTTPBody:jsonData];
                  [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

            NSLog(@"%@", [request allHTTPHeaderFields]);
            NSURLSessionConfiguration *configuration = [NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration];
            NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:configuration];
            [[session dataTaskWithRequest:request completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse* response, NSError *error)
            {
                NSString *response= [[NSString alloc]initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
                NSLog(@"%@", response);

                if(!error) NSLog(@"Done \n");

            }] resume];

        }
}
```

From the server side, I've written a php (5.0, deprecated but it's just for just for excercise purposes) script which is:

```
    <?php

        $con = mysql_connect("something", "username", "password");
        if(!$con)
            die("Error during connection" . mysql_error());

        $db_selected = mysql_select_db("DB", $con);

        $uploaddir = "./aFolder/";
        $user = basename($_FILES['photo']['name']);
        $storeName = $uploaddir.$user;
        echo $storeName. "\n ";

        if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['photo']['tmp_name'], $uploadfile))
            echo 'The photo has been inserted in the database\n';
         else die("The photo hasn't been copied. \n " . mysql_error());


        $jsondata = file_get_contents('php://input');
        $textFields = json_decode($jsondata, true);

        $review = $data['review'];
        $grade = $data['grade'];

        //Echoing for debug purposes
        echo $review . " " . $grade . "\n ";

        mysql_close($con);
?>
```

The problem I'm facing is that I don't receive nothing from the server side: the connection can be estabilished but it seems like neither feilds are sent. What I should want to achieve is that I can copy the image in a folder inside my database and retrieving a response which contains the text of the two fields sent in the JSON array, echoed from the server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should choose either JSON request (in which case you'd include the image as a base64-encoded string) or multipart request (in which are you'd just include the two string values as additional parts of the request), but not both. I might use JSON if I was sending some very rich structure (e.g. nested array of dictionaries), but give the simple structure here (two strings), I'd lean towards a simple multipart request.

Unfortunately, the building of the multipart request, above, isn't quite right. I'd refer you to https://stackoverflow.com/a/24252378/1271826, which can upload files as well as supply text fields. Or consider using a framework like [AFNetworking](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking), which gets you out of the weeds or creating this request.

In terms of processing the response on the server, since the client code specified that it would accept a JSON response, I assume you'd like the server to build such response. See point #2 in https://stackoverflow.com/a/20196541/1271826 for an example of `mysqli` or `PDO_MySQL` (notably, not using the deprecated `mysql` interface from your code sample; see http://php.net/manual/en/intro.mysql.php) code that

- receives `multi-part/formdata` request,
- [escapes](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php) the values or does `?` binding,
- inserts data into your database, and
- then builds JSON responses.

Obviously, you would still receive the file using the `move_uploaded_file` in your original code snippet, but you access these two text fields using `$_POST` parameters and you can retire that `file_get_contents('php://input')` pattern, which is used for JSON requests only.